# Can I ask for research experiment participants here?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on my masters thesis and will be looking for participants to attempt to hack a server and bypass a new protocol I've invented. Is it alright to advertise my research here?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's beyond the scope of the site.

Comment: Should be okay to drop in the chat, though, or not?

Comment: sure, but there is usually only a very small group there